# feel embarrassed vs feel it embarrassing

Tags: grammaticality, syntax

> a. She felt embarrassed to be asked such a private question.

> b. She felt it embarrassing to be asked such a private question.

Are both the statements grammatically correct?

Comment: They both seem fine to me.

Comment: @ John Gordon, Thanks. Suppose I change Sentence b  into this: She considered it shame to be asked such a private question. Is it also grammatically correct?

Comment: _shameful_ would be correct.

Comment: The "circumlocution" of the second format above is far more "stylised", and it's probably best avoided by non-native speakers because it's not easy to identify which versions of this relatively complex syntax are idiomatic, and which aren't.

Comment: Check out [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt+embarrassed+to%2Cfelt+it+embarrassing+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20embarrassed%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfelt%20it%20embarrassing%20to%3B%2Cc0) for relative frequency of the two formats. (You probably want to stick with the majority! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree. Actually, I sometimes find it hard to differentiate the usage of the complements in  these two versions. Version 1:  I consider it a shame to have failed the exam.  (a noun as a complement); Version 2: I consider it shameful to be kicked out for no reason.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to "differentiate" your two alternatives in that last comment. Native speakers will often disagree about *which* versions of that construction work at all, AND/OR whether, for example, *considering something [to be] **shameful*** might mean something different to *considering it [to be] **a shame***. I recommend sticking with plain unadorned *I **am ashamed** to [be / have been] kicked out for no reason*.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are grammatically correct but they are different semantically.

a. She felt embarrassed by the question.
b. She felt that asking such a private question was embarrassing. *It doesn't necessarily mean she was embarrassed by it.*

Comment: I think it's slightly "clutching at straws" to differentiate the two on the basis that the circumlocutory version might imply she felt that the embarrassment attached to the people asking the question, rather than to her on the receiving end of it! Mostly the difference is that one is completely natural for normal conversational contexts, and the other is a highly stylised construction more likely to be found in literary texts.